# Different method to calculate blob area in OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use a different method to calculate a blob area from contourArea, using the `countNonZero` function. I want to see if there is significant approximation introduced by `contourArea` function, and also be able to calculate area of contour with auto-intersection.

```
cv::findContours(drawingIn, contoursIn, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


double max=0;
double currentarea=0;
int currentareaCounted = 0;
int maxAreaCounted = 0;

for (unsigned int i=0;i<contoursIn.size();i++)
{
    currentarea=cv::contourArea(contoursIn[i]);
    cv::Mat drawingMatCount = cv::Mat::zeros(ROI_INTERACTION,ROI_INTERACTION, CV_8UC1);
    cv::drawContours(drawingMatCount, contoursIn, i, 255, -1, 8);
    currentareaCounted = cv::countNonZero(drawingMatCount);

    if (currentarea>max)
        max=currentarea;      
    if (currentareaCounted>maxAreaCounted)
        maxAreaCounted=currentareaCounted;

}
```

Is there something that could be improved? This code works, but my doubt is about declaring a new matrix every iteration. Could this lead to some performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

- Declare `drawingMatCount` once before the loop
- `cv::drawContours(drawingMatCount, contoursIn, i, 0, -1, 8);`  at the end of the loop

BTW: this is not the blob area, its the contour area, including the holes.